# Ionic- self-signed https certificate exception on ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, https, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

We are developing an hybrid mobile app in ionic to get data from server and display it in app. 
We have a self signed certificate to query to our server. We have placed the .cer file in xcode project->target for iOS.
It is giving exception for https query using the certificate.

Our dev environment versions are as below:
ionic version 3.20.0

we are using following plugin for http.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Ionic code is as below

```
let head = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
      'Accept':'application/json',
      'content-type':'application/json'
    }


this.http.enableSSLPinning(true).then(data =>{
  console.log("SSL success");
 })
 .catch(error =>{
   console.log("SSL error");
 });
 this.http.acceptAllCerts(true);
 this.http.setDataSerializer("json");
    this.http.post(this.getProfileURL, requestData, head)
  .then(data => {
console.log("success");
  resolve(JSON.parse(data.data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
   reject(error.error);

  });
});
```

THis code works on Android and not in iOS
It is giving below error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Questions:
1. Is the location of the certificate correct? (We have placed the .cer file in xcode project->target for iOS.)
2. Which certificate type should we use - .cer, .der, .pem?
3. How do I resolve NSInvalidArgumentException?

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I could resolve this by doing following steps:
1. place the .der file at location - project->target OR www/certificates
2. In your iOS swift code, go to the file AFSecurityPolicy.m in method certificatesInBundle, and change bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"cer" to bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"der"

Comment: We are facing similar issue with iOS and Android both, can you please help. It is giving certificate error. Here is my code:
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP, HTTPResponse } from '@ionic-native/http';
constructor(private _mHTTP: HTTP) { }

this._mHTTP.get(path, {}, headers).then((d) => {
      let t: T = this.convertReturn<T>(d.data);
      return t;
    })

Currently getting Error code: 0

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and my problem was the format of the certificate.
Initially the format was PEM and in iOS you need to use the DER format.

If this is your case, you can easily convert your certificate using the following `open_ssl` command:

`openssl x509 -outform der -in myCertificate.cer -out myFormattedCertificate.cer`

*Hint: You can easily check if your certificate is in PEM format if you open it in a text editor such as Sublime Text. You will see that starts with something like this: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"*